# Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem, role of $g$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, intuition, sufficient-statistics

The theorem states that $\tilde Y=T(Y)$ is a sufficient statistic for $X$ iff $p(y|x) = h(y)g(\tilde y | x)$ where $p(y|x)$ is the conditional pdf of $Y$ and $h$ and $g$ are some positive functions.

What I'm wondering is what role $g$ plays here. I am trying to prove that something is NOT a sufficient statistic and if I have to pick $g(\tilde y|x) = p(\tilde y | x)k(y)\ell(x)$ where $p(\tilde y|x)$ is the conditional pdf of $\tilde Y$ and $k,\ell$ are arbitrary then I am done. But of course this doesn't strictly preclude the existence of some other function for which the condition holds. I'm struggling to understand the role of $g$, simply put. Can anyone shed some intuition, given my admittedly diffuse preamble?

Comment: Like, why isn't $\frac{p(y|x)}{p(\tilde y|x} = f(x)g(y)$ sufficient and necessary?

Comment: I am indeed not sure where the problem exactly lies, but what makes $g$ so "interesting" a function in the factorization theorem is that it depends on the data $Y$ only through the sufficient statistic $\tilde Y$, whereas in your expression $g(\tilde y|x) = p(\tilde y | x)k(y)\ell(x)$, the right-hand side does depend on $y$, so it cannot really be an equality.